# Find first root of a black box function, or any negative value of same function

Tags: algorithm, search, mathematical-optimization, orbital-mechanics

I have a black box function, f(x) and a range of values for x.
I need to find the lowest value of x for which f(x) = 0.

I know that for the start of the range of x, f(x) > 0, and if I had a value for which f(x) < 0 I could use regula falsi, or similar root finding methods, to try determine f(x)=0.

I know f(x) is continuous, and should only have 0,1 or 2 roots for the range in question, but it might have a local minimum.

f(x) is somewhat computationally expensive, and I'll have to find this first root a lot.

I was thinking some kind of hill climbing with a degree of randomness to avoid any local minimums, but then how do you know if there was no minimum less than zero or if you just haven't found it yet? I think the function shouldn't have more than two minimum points, but I can't be absolutely certain of that enough to rely on it.

If it helps, x in this case represents a time, and f(x) represents the distance between a ship and a body in orbit (moon/planet) at that time. I need the first point where they are a certain distance from each other.

Comment: have you implemented given below solution? Is there a way to view the result?

Comment: I did. I translated it into C# and used MathNet.Numerics for some of the matrix operations. It worked perfectly. I set about building it into a reusable library, but I got a new job and life got in the way so it is unfinished. I really should finish it, finishing things is always the hardest part.

Comment: Maybe you will allow me to view the result? I am also playing with creating 2D game which using celestial mechanics, I am heavily interested in investigating any chosen solutions related to this thematic.

Comment: I'll dig it out, clean it up if it needs it and put it somewhere I can share it with you. Are you specifically looking for the encounter solver, or other orbital mechanics code?

Comment: Now, yes, I am working under encounter code, but any other code related to that thematic would be also appreciated.

Comment: Hey, how is it?

Comment: When I went back to the code I found that I had left it half way through making changes at a challenging change. I also left the overall project in a state that would not compile. I had planned on fixing it enough to put the whole project on github (or similar) to share, but rather than make you wait for that I'm going to include a link to a paste of the C# conversion I made of Rody's MatLab function. https://pastebin.com/7bezpjtP

Comment: Thanks! But, not sure if I'm doing something wrong, since it is not working. E.g. for test I'm trying to find roots of y=(x-3)^2-1 (roots = {2, 4}) on interval [0, 10] with 300 steps, and I'm receiving 4 roots and very sad accuracy https://i.imgur.com/WNHUDn3.png Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Code I'm using - https://pastebin.com/7u54ihim Also, what MathNet version did you use? I tried it on 3.9.0

Comment: This is the test I used when writing the function in C# https://pastebin.com/vaQNz5P7. I compared my output with the output from the Matlab version for the same function, I don't know why I chose that modified version of sinc, I must have seen it somewhere as a suggestion. It passes for me with MathNet.Numerics 3.9.0 and 3.20.0.

Maybe there is something about that equation that is unsuited to this solver? When I run your test I get 5 results:
root = 1.87935507576128
root = 4.00284873016215
root = 4.02675166239092
root = 4.0744226021598
root = 10.0000251451567

Comment: All pastbins are not available. @VictorF could you please share them again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My method will sound pretty complicated, but in the end the computation time of the method will be far smaller than the distance calculations (evaluation of your `f(x)`). Also, there are quite many implementations of it already written up in existing libraries.

So what I would do:

- approximate `f(x)` with a Chebychev polynomial
- find the real roots of that polynomial
- If any are found, use those roots as initial estimates in a more precise rootfinder (if needed)

Given the nature of your function (smooth, continuous, otherwise well-behaved) and the information that there's 0,1 or 2 roots, a good Chebychev polynomial can already be found with 3 evaluations of `f(x)`.

Then find the eigenvalues of the companion matrix of the Chebychev coefficients; these correspond to the roots of the Chebychev polynomial.

If all are imaginary, there's 0 roots.
If there are some real roots, check if two are equal (that "rare" case you spoke of). 
Otherwise, all real eigenvalues are roots; the lowest one of which is the root you seek.

Then use Newton-Raphson to refine (if necessary, or use a better Chebychev polynomial). Derivatives of `f` can be approximated using central differences

```
f'(x) = ( f(x+h)-f(h-x) ) /2/h     (for small h)
```

I have an implementation of the Chebychev routines in Matlab/Octave (given below). Use like this:

```
R = FindRealRoots(@f, x_min, x_max, 5, true,true);
```

with `[x_min,x_max]` your range in `x`, `5` the number of points to use for finding the polynomial (the higher, the more accurate. Equals the amount of function evaluations needed), and the last `true` will make a plot of the actual function and the Chebychev approximation to it (mainly for testing purposes).

Now, the implementation:

```
% FINDREALROOTS     Find approximations to all real roots of any function 
%                   on an interval [a, b].
%
% USAGE:
%    Roots = FindRealRoots(funfcn, a, b, n, vectorized, make_plot)
%
% FINDREALROOTS() approximates all the real roots of the function 'funfcn' 
% in the interval [a,b]. It does so by finding the roots of an [n]-th degree 
% Chebyshev polynomial approximation, via the eignevalues of the associated 
% companion matrix. 
%
% When the argument [vectorized] is [true], FINDREALROOTS() will evaluate 
% the function 'funfcn' at all [n] required points in the interval 
% simultaneously. Otherwise, it will use ARRAFUN() to calculate the [n] 
% function values one-by-one. [vectorized] defaults to [false]. 
%
% When the argument [make_plot] is true, FINDREALROOTS() plots the 
% original function and the Chebyshev approximation, and shows any roots on
% the given interval. Also [make_plot] defaults to [false]. 
%
% All [Roots] (if any) will be sorted.
% 
% First version 26th May 2007 by Stephen Morris, 
% Nightingale-EOS Ltd., St. Asaph, Wales.
%
% Modified 14/Nov (Rody Oldenhuis)
%
% See also roots, eig.

function Roots = FindRealRoots(funfcn, a, b, n, vectorized, make_plot)

    % parse input and initialize.
    inarg = nargin; 
    if n <= 2, n = 3; end                    % Minimum [n] is 3:    
    if (inarg < 5), vectorized = false; end  % default: function isn't vectorized
    if (inarg < 6), make_plot = false; end   % default: don't make plot

    % some convenient variables
    bma = (b-a)/2;  bpa = (b+a)/2;  Roots = [];

    % Obtain the Chebyshev coefficients for the function
    %
    % Based on the routine given in Numerical Recipes (3rd) section 5.8;
    % calculates the Chebyshev coefficients necessary to approximate some
    % function over the interval [a,b]

    % initialize 
    c = zeros(1,n);  k=(1:n)';  y = cos(pi*((1:n)-1/2)/n); 
    % evaluate function on Chebychev nodes
    if vectorized
        f = feval(funfcn,(y*bma)+bpa);
    else
        f = arrayfun(@(x) feval(funfcn,x),(y*bma)+bpa);
    end

    % compute the coefficients
    for j=1:n, c(j)=(f(:).'*(cos((pi*(j-1))*((k-0.5)/n))))*(2-(j==1))/n; end       

    % coefficients may be [NaN] if [inf]
    % ??? TODO - it is of course possible for c(n) to be zero...
    if any(~isfinite(c(:))) || (c(n) == 0), return; end

    % Define [A] as the Frobenius-Chebyshev companion matrix. This is based
    % on the form given by J.P. Boyd, Appl. Num. Math. 56 pp.1077-1091 (2006).
    one = ones(n-3,1);
    A = diag([one/2; 0],-1) + diag([1; one/2],+1);
    A(end, :) = -c(1:n-1)/2/c(n);
    A(end,end-1) = A(end,end-1) + 0.5;

    % Now we have the companion matrix, we can find its eigenvalues using the
    % MATLAB built-in function. We're only interested in the real elements of
    % the matrix:
    eigvals = eig(A);  realvals = eigvals(imag(eigvals)==0);

    % if there aren't any real roots, return
    if isempty(realvals), return; end

    % Of course these are the roots scaled to the canonical interval [-1,1]. We
    % need to map them back onto the interval [a, b]; we widen the interval just
    % a tiny bit to make sure that we don't miss any that are right on the 
    % boundaries.
    rangevals = nonzeros(realvals(abs(realvals) <= 1+1e-5));

    % also sort the roots
    Roots = sort(rangevals*bma + bpa);

    % As a sanity check we'll plot out the original function and its Chebyshev
    % approximation: if they don't match then we know to call the routine again
    % with a larger 'n'.
    if make_plot
        % simple grid
        grid = linspace(a,b, max(25,n));
        % evaluate function
        if vectorized
            fungrid = feval(funfcn, grid);
        else
            fungrid = arrayfun(@(x) feval(funfcn,x), grid);
        end        
        % corresponding Chebychev-grid (more complicated but essentially the same)
        y = (2.*grid-a-b)./(b-a); d = zeros(1,length(grid)); dd = d;
        for j = length(c):-1:2, sv=d; d=(2*y.*d)-dd+c(j); dd=sv; end, chebgrid=(y.*d)-dd+c(1);
        % Now make plot
        figure(1), clf,  hold on
        plot(grid, fungrid ,'color' , 'r');
        line(grid, chebgrid,'color' , 'b'); 
        line(grid, zeros(1,length(grid)), 'linestyle','--')
        legend('function', 'interpolation')
    end % make plot

end % FindRealRoots
```

Comment: That looks interesting. So from a few samples of f(x) a polynomial can be made for which the eigenvalues should approximate the actual roots of the original function? If that works it could prove to be much more efficient, yes. I'd tried a hill climb but it might miss a low enough point and I'd prefer something more reliable.

I'll have to get something to calculate eigenvalues and then give this a try.

Also, I saw your comment on my other question but couldn't see your email address. I think mine is listed on my profile and I would appreciate any further information you have on this topic.

Comment: @pagnatious: I did these calculations professionally in the past, in the context of collision avoidance (detect close encounters between the international space station and space debris). I also did it once in the context of interplanetary mission design (try to have a spacecraft bound for Jupiter have as many close encounters with asteroids in the asteroid belt as possible). Finding *all* close encounters is pretty important for these things, so this is the method I used in both cases.

Comment: @pagnatious: For the interplanetary mission: I used a data set of half a million asteroids, and the optimizer found the close encounters for all asteroids thousands of times for a single run, and a single run never took longer than a few minutes, so I'd say it is plenty fast enough. Especially when a reduction to 2D would allow for a few more shortcuts you could use. Anyway, I think I'm not seeing your e-mail address, and you're not seeing mine, but we're only seeing our own :) Mine is [my last name] [at] gmail dot com; drop me a line and I'll gladly help you with this.

Comment: Took a bit of figuring out to understand what was going on, but using DotNetMatrix for its Eigenvalue decomposition I converted and tested that MATLAB function and it found the point of encounter. Next step is integrating the function and making full use of it. Thank you.

Comment: This is the C# conversion I ultimately made and used of this matlab function. If I get around to tidying and releasing the full library I was working on I'll also provide a link to that here. https://pastebin.com/7bezpjtP

Comment: @pagnatious the link https://pastebin.com/7bezpjtP is not available.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, I wonder if you could share your thoughts on the line you marked with TODO. If the last coefficient is zero you return "no roots". I understand this is necessary for eigenvalues not to blow up, but generally speaking, what would the zero in the last coefficient space signal? Could we round it up to some small value \epsilon instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [secant method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) which is a discrete version of Newton's method.

[image]

The root is estimated by calculating the line between two points (= the secant) and its crossing of the X axis.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't have the same initial requirement of the starting values having opposite sings, but it does still require me to find good starting values. Is it reliable? Even the diagram for it on that wiki link presents a situation where it won't converge.

Comment: Terms to ask Google include "safeguarded zero-finding" and "Brent's method" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method).

Comment: Brent's Method looks to have a nice mix of speed and robustness due to the combined approaches, but it still needs initial values of opposing signs. Safeguarding seems to be about detecting that a solver isn't going to resolve to the root and stopping, which could be applied perhaps to detecting scenarios where there is no root, but it seems you'd be more in danger of just telling that it failed, and not that it could never have succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has only 0, 1 or 2 roots, so it can be done using an algorithm it doesn't ensure the first root.

- Find one root using Newton's method or other method. If it can't find any root, this algorithm also give up.
- Let the found root is `r` and beginning of the range of the x is `x0`. let `d = (r-x0)/2`.
- While `d > 0`, calculate `f(r-d)`. if `f(r-d) > 0`, half `d` (`d := d / 2`) and loop. if
  `f(r-d) <= 0`, escape the loop.
- if loop is finished by `d = 0`, report `r` as the first root. if `d > 0`, find a root between `x0` and `r-d` by using any other method and report it.

I assumed two prerequiesite conditions.

1. f(x) takes x of floating point numbers
2. At each point of the roots of f(x), the graph of f(x) *crosses* to x-axis. They are not *touching* root like x=0 in f(x)=x^2.

Using condition 2, you can prove that if there is no point such that `f(r-d) < 0`, `∀ x: x0 < x < r, f(x) > 0`.

Comment: It is difficult to find any root of the function. Getting a derivative of the function isn't possible so Newton's method isn't an option, and many of the other reliable ones seem to need a definite point either side of the root. Also is it possible that the one root only touches the x axis, not actually crossing, unlikely, but possible.

Comment: Hm, I've missed "or any negative value of same function"? Anyway, for almost any algorithm, you can create a pathological example of __continuous__ function. Almost is for an inefficient algorithm which checks all value of f(x) for all x in the dense subset of the range.

Comment: In this case, I don't think your function (distance between ship and star?) is such a evil function, so secant method (@axel-kemper proposed) may be the alternative of Newton's method. **Ensuring no root needs check on every sufficiently dense points**. Finding good initial value should be repeated until you find one root or run out all initial values you can try. Withtout knowledge about f(x), this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a small change to the `uniroot.all` function from the R library rootSolve.

```
uniroot.all <- function (f, interval, lower= min(interval),
                         upper= max(interval), tol= .Machine$double.eps^0.2,
                         maxiter= 1000, n = 100, nroots = -1, ... ) {

  ## error checking as in uniroot...
  if (!missing(interval) && length(interval) != 2)
    stop("'interval' must be a vector of length 2")
  if (!is.numeric(lower) || !is.numeric(upper) || lower >=
      upper)
    stop("lower < upper  is not fulfilled")

  ## subdivide interval in n subintervals and estimate the function values
  xseq <- seq(lower,upper,len=n+1)
  mod  <- f(xseq,...)

  ## some function values may already be 0
  Equi <- xseq[which(mod==0)]

  ss   <- mod[1:n]*mod[2:(n+1)]  # interval where functionvalues change sign
  ii   <- which(ss<0)

  for (i in ii) {
    Equi <- c(Equi, uniroot(f, lower = xseq[i], upper = xseq[i+1] ,...)$root)
    if (length(Equi) == nroots) {
      return(Equi)
    }
  }
  return(Equi)
}
```

And run it like this:

```
uniroot.all(f = your_function, interval = c(start, stop), nroots = 1)
```