# Find the first root and local maximum/minimum of a function

Tags: math

### Problem

I want to find

- The first root
- The first local minimum/maximum

of a black-box function in a given range.

The function has following properties:

- It's continuous and differentiable.
- It's combination of constant and periodic functions. All periods are known.

(It's better if it can be done with weaker assumptions)

What is the fastest way to get the root and the extremum?

Do I need more assumptions or bounds of the function?

### What I've tried

I know I can use [root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm). What I don't know is how to find the first root efficiently.

It needs to be fast enough so that it can run within a few miliseconds with precision of 1.0 and range of 1.0e+8, which is the problem.

Since the range could be quite large and it should be precise enough, I can't brute-force it by checking all the possible subranges.

I considered [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Bisection_method), but it's too slow to find the first root if the function has only one big root in the range, as every subrange should be checked.

---

It's preferable if the solution is in java, but any similar language is fine.

---

### Background

I want to calculate when arbitrary celestial object reaches certain height.

It's a configuration-defined virtual object, so I can't assume anything about the object.

It's not easy to get either analytical solution or simple approximation because various coordinates are involved.

I decided to find a numerical solution for this.

Comment: So, for the first root, read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501182/find-first-root-of-a-black-box-function-or-any-negative-value-of-same-function

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It looks like a homework assignment without any effort beyond cut & paste.

Comment: Wait, what? No it isn't. How could something like this be a homework assignment? For what? I'm writing a program with configurable celestial objects on my own since I'm enthusiastic in space. No one is making me do this.

Comment: You should abandon your millisecond SLA.  Make it run, make it run right, make it run fast.  Post code and ask specific questions.  Until you do, we have to assume that you've written none.

Comment: I've not written anything since I've not found any solution for this specific problem. I can write simple bisection method. But I didn't, it won't solve my problem in any sense. Why should I do that.  I guess I might have posted this on wrong stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general black box function, this can't really be done. Any root finding algorithm on a black box function can't guarantee that it has found all the roots or any particular root, even if the function is continuous and differentiable.

The property of being periodic gives a bit more hope, but you can still have periodic functions with infinitely many roots in a bounded domain. Given that your function relates to celestial objects, this isn't likely to happen. Assuming your periodic functions are sinusoidal, I believe you can get away with checking subranges on the order of one-quarter of the shortest period (out of all the periodic components).

Maybe try [Brent's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method) on the shortest quarter period subranges?

---

Another approach would be to apply your root finding algorithm iteratively. If your range is (*a*, *b*), then apply your algorithm to that range to find a root at say *c* < *b*. Then apply your algorithm to the range (*a*, *c*) to find a root in that range. Continue until no more roots are found. The last root you found is a good candidate for your minimum root.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I can have the case of [tidal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking), where two rotations are cancelled (viewed on horizontal coordinates). So I need to either special-case it, or deal with it. This is why I can't simply use the shortest period.

Comment: Thanks! I think your kind solution will work with just a bit more assumptions! (Such as 'maximal speed')

Answer (score 0):

Black box function for any range? You cannot even be sure it has the continuous domain over that range. What kind of solutions are you looking for? Natural numbers, integers, real numbers, complex? These are all the question that greatly impact the answer.

So 1st thing should be determining what kind of number you accept as the result. 
Second is having some kind of protection against limes of function that will try to explode your calculations as it goes for plus or minus infinity.

Since we are touching the limes topics you could have your solution edge towards zero and look like a solution but never touch 0 and become a solution. This depends on your margin of error, how close something has to be to be considered ok, it's good enough.

I think for this your **SIMPLEST TO IMPLEMENT** bet for real number solutions (I assume those) is to take an interval and this **divide and conquer algorithm:**

- Take lower and upper border and middle value (or approx middle value for infinity decimals border/borders)

  - Try to calculate solution with all 3 and have some kind of protection against infinities
  - remember all 3 values in an array with results from them (3 pair of values)
  - remember the current best value (one its closest to solution) in seperate variable (a pair of value and result for that value)
  - STEP FORWARD - repeat above with 1st -2nd value range and 2nd -3rd value range
  - have a new pair of value and result to be closest to solution.
  - clear the old value-result pairs, replace them with new ones gotten from this iteration while remembering the best value solution pair (total)

Repeat above for how precise you wish to get and look at that memory explode with each iteration, keep in mind you are gonna to have exponential growth of values there. It can be further improved if you lets say take one interval and go as deep as you wanna, remember best value-result pair and then delete all other memory and go for next interval and dig deep.